# Amazon's Website Search Bar

Tags: usability, user-expectation, search, drop-down-list

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Did you notice the change in the results being shown in the drop-down?
In the first image, only last words are highlighted in bold but in case of the second image the moment user keys in spacebar once again it turns all the results into bold. Why is it so?

Answer (score 7):

When you hit the spacebar once again, Amazon treats it as an incorrect word and highlight it.

Same happens with Google - when you enter an incorrect word, it highlights it.

[image]

Entering an incorrect word:

[image]

Comment: But in the above the example the text entered is right. There's an extra space given by the user. Why does it highlight the entire text?

Comment: Seems like adding an extra space after a word makes it incorrect in Amazon search. They may not have handled this case. I don't if it's a bug or feature. Depends on your interpretation.

Answer (score 5):

It is the way the autocomplete is designed.

When the user starts typing a word the application goes through the previous/popular searches and displays the possible continuation in block letters on the list.

And when the user types an extra space after a word, there are no such previous/popular searches that exist, so the whole sentence changes to block letters as the text in input field does not match with the list of previous/popular searches.

When they continue to type any other word after two spaces the autocomplete will suggest the existing searches in block letters with only one space.

### Case 1

**mobile** - Available in previous searches. So, only display continuation in block letters

mobile **phone**, mobile **charger**, etc..

### Case 2

**mobile p** - Available in previous searches. So, only display continuation in block letters

mobile p**hone**, mobile p**hone case**, etc..

### Case 3

**mobile**  * (mobile double space) - Not available. So, display all popular searcher in block letters

**mobile phone**, **mobile case**, **mobile charger**, etc..

### Case 4

**mobile  p** (mobile double space p) - Not available. So, display all popular searcher in block letters

**mobile phone**, **mobile phone charger**, **mobile phone case**, etc..

Answer (score 0):

It is detected as a "wrong word" , probably somewhere along development a searched word with an extra spacebar is seen as a whole word that does not match with the right word that was "mobile" as "mobile" is not the same thing with "mobile " .